# Can i set startup folder of tfileopendialog to a shell (non file system) folder?

Tags: shell, dialog, namespaces

Can i set startup folder of tfileopendialog to a shell (non file system) folder, and how? If not, is there other way to save the full dialog state for the next call of the application?

Answer (score 0):

Ok if no one will bother answering i will.

```
    dialog.shellitem.getdisplayname(SIGDN_DESKTOPABSOLUTEPARSING,pch);
```

assigns "::{guid}\..." value to pch variable, and this string can be used to set dialog.defaultfolder or dialog.filename. it can also be used in conjunction with

```
    shellfolder.getdisplaynameof(pidl,SHGDN_FORPARSING,strret);
```

to identify a folder.